Run a method after wordpress post gets published, whether it's scheduled or not
I'm trying to run a method whenever a post is published, both when it's scheduled or immediately.
I've already tried:

future_to_publish
transition_post_status
publish_future_post
publish_post

All of these either don't trigger the code, or the post object that's associated is just empty and there's no way to do anything with the post values.
I've had the post_id come back to me, but whenever I try to get the post object, it's all empty.

Can you post your code to help better?
